# Web2py: How to pass arguments from view to controller to delete a record from DB

Tags: web2py

I have a table and on each row I have a "Delete" button. What I want to do is pass the row id through onclick function of that button to a "delete" function on controller.

My controller

```
def studentDelete():
    rec_id = request.args(0)
    crud.delete(db.student, rec_id,next=URL('Home','Students_List'))
```

My view (when I click on the button, shows a modal to help the user confirm or cancel the delete action. #warning is the id of the accept button from the modal if the user decides to delete the record.)

```
<div class='btn-group btn-group-justified JpositionA'><a class='btn btn-warning Jview btn-xs opciones'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a></div>;

<script>
$(document).on('click', '.opciones', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      btn = $(this);
      var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
      var row = tabla.row( tr );
      var datos=row.data();
      var id_record=datos.student.id;

      $('#myModal').modal('show')
     .one('click', '#warning', function(e) {
                     ajax('{{=URL('Tools', 'studentDelete')}}' + '?value=' + id_record);
          });
        });
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Javascript code is sending the record ID to the server in the query string as the `value` variable, but the Python code is expecting the ID in `request.args`. You can simply change the Python code to:

```
    rec_id = request.get_vars.value
```